# Como recuperar campo do tipo date (mysql+php)?

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um campo do tipo date em mysql, o problema é que não consigo recupera-lo, ao seleciona-lo e imprimir só aparece o nome dele (data).

```
$dados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT 'data' FROM tabela");

$res_data = mysqli_fetch_array($dados);

echo $res_data[0];
```

Saída --- `data`.

Comment: `var_dump($res_data);` dá o que ?

Comment: Não precisa colocar o campo entre aspas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tire as aspas do nome da coluna:

```
$dados = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT data FROM tabela");
```